# How to check if multiple tables have rows for given ID

Tags: sql

I have master table with several details tables. I need to check if each of the details tables have any rows for given ID. Right now I am going through all the tables and checking if count>0 but there must be a better way.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Table1 WHERE ID=3;
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Table2 WHERE ID=3;
...
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM TableN WHERE ID=3;
```

Is there a way to do this in one effective SQL statement?

Comment: How are these tables related? By your original post, they're just random tables that may not have the same structure.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?  Are you trying to avoid scanning all tables, reduce duplicate code, or just get one result set?

Comment: Tables are related. Master table has primary key ID. Details tables has foreign key Table1.ID.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you really want one *result set* you can do:

```
DECLARE @ID INT
SET @ID = 3

SELECT 'Table1' TableName, COUNT(*) FROM Table1 WHERE ID=@ID;
UNION
SELECT 'Table2' TableName, COUNT(*) FROM Table2 WHERE ID=@ID;
UNION
...
UNION
SELECT 'TableN' TableName, COUNT(*) FROM TableN WHERE ID=@ID;
```

I don't see a way to *not* scan all tables if that's what you're trying to avoid.

Answer (score 1):

```
WITH CTE AS 
(
SELECT 'T1' AS Name, COUNT(*) AS Total FROM Table1 WHERE ID=3
UNION ALL
SELECT 'T2' AS Name, COUNT(*) AS Total  FROM Table2 WHERE ID=3
UNION ALL
...
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Tn' AS Name, COUNT(*) AS Total FROM TableN WHERE ID=3;
)
Select * from CTE where Total > 0
```

Comment: He will still has to go over all tables, which is what he is trying to avoid.

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like poor design of your tables.  I think you need to either combine some tables or add a bridge table that you can query.

Or, keep querying the individual tables if you structure is optimal and just have your application deal with running each one.